# How to do an if statement bash linux

Tags: linux, bash

How do I fix this? It just skips the if statement.
I am trying to do an if statement that finds if the group entered meets the right criteria.

```
if $groupchosen== "student"; then
```

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement requires a command, not a bare comparison. Use `test` (or its alias, `[`).

```
if [ "$groupchosen" = 'student' ] then
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) a look. But long story short:

```
if [ "foo" = "foo" ]; then
    echo expression evaluated as true
fi
```